# Sending Cisco NCS/Prime Infrastructure reports without encapsulating them in a zip

Tags: cisco, wireless, management

Is it possible to configure Cisco NCS/Prime Infrastructure to send reports via email without encapsulating them in a zip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have requested the same thing, and been told that they must be zipped. No real explanation why this must be the case, but there weren't any hints that things were going to change any time soon!

Answer (score 4):

As of Cisco Prime Infrastructure 1.3 (which is the latest version of WCS/NCS), this is not possible. I have heard that many people have asked Cisco about this, but reports sent via email still must be encapsulated in a zip file.